# Asp.Net Mvc remote validation textbox focus issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

I have a single textbox on a form - basically to allow users to change the URL of their site in our mini CMS. We use remote validation to check that the URL is not already taken.

They enter their desired URL and hit the save button. If they do just that and the focus goes from the textbox straight to the submit button - the validation does not happen and the form doesn't submit properly. If they tap into an area of whitespace then the form does.

The issue with the form submitting is that if they tap whitespace we get the name of the submit button posted along with the desired URL - we use the ([AcceptParameterAttribute](http://blogs.sonatribe.com/wayne/2011/08/15/acceptparameterattribute-update/#comment-470)) to allow us to route form submits to the right Action. This uses the submit buttons name attribute to do this. If they don't click whitespace to lose focus on the text box then only the desired URL is posted.

This is a really odd one and it is very annoying. Has anyone seen anything like this before? Is there a way to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following script to the page:

```
$(":input").live("blur", function () {
    $(this.form).validate().element(this);
});
```

This should cause validation to occur when you click on the submit button.  If not, try changing the first line to:

```
$(":submit").live("click", function () {
```

Comment: works like a charm locally - not on the server though - i'm guessing there's a race condition? it returns before the validate has happened?

Comment: Quite likely.  Try the solution I posted here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840634/how-to-get-unobtrusive-jquery-remote-validator-to-perform-async/7841104#7841104.  This will allow you to wait on completion of the remote validation.